# header("Location: /") redirect in template file only works if user is logged in. Why?

Tags: theming, redirection

I was developing a new feature for a client, and deployed it live today.  However, due to circumstances out of my control, they decided to implement an alternative solution and asked me to implement a temporary redirect.

This feature was a standalone full screen flash app that did not fit the site theme at all.  So, I implemented the page as a custom `html--pagename.tpl.php` file and loaded the page-specific JS and CSS.  It is a custom template for an existing content type.

Now, since the client wants a temporary redirect, I added

```
header("Location: /");
```

as the first line of PHP code in the template to redirect any access to that URL to the index page.  However, this only works if the user is logged in.  Anyone 
else can view this page and the header code seems to be ignored for some reason.

This URL loads regardless of the Published status set to Published or Unpublished.  In the morning, I will modify the `.htaccess` to execute a 302 redirect, but would like an explanation for this behavior for future reference.

Comment: try this **drupal_goto('<front>');**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output of the tpl files is cached for anonymous users. But only their text output is, that's how [Output Control Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) in PHP works. That's why Drupal API functions will not work as intended, either. They may do their job, all right, by serving as cache breakers, but you do not want to break cache on a busy website, as it may be a server killer.

Most stable way of doing temporary redirections is, as far as I found, an .htaccess way. mod_rewrite is already used by Drupal, so it cost you nothing in additional binaries loaded to memory, and it acts before PHP is even started. As [described in this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12045566/2389310), you can do this like that:

```
RewriteRule ^example/my-stuff/$ /example/home/ [L,R=301]
```

Put it before Drupal redirects, but in the same section.

If you need a PHP logic to decide if redirect is needed, you can do it using [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) instead:

1. Substitute original callback with yours
2. Perform any logic needed
3. Log to watchdog if you want to
4. - Call original callback and return it's result if you are not redirecting, or
   - Redirect with [`drupal_goto('<front>')`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7)

Comment: I dont attention this note, yes , your answer is better

Comment: @zhilevan I had an opportunity to fail at this issue already. On a busy site. I just don't want others to have the problems I gave myself then :D

Comment: You are awesome molot ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as it does make sense to why different page load functionality exists in regard to login status.  Fortunately, this was a URL that had not gone public as of yet, so the damage is minimal.

Comment: @Jason actually there are modules that cache some pages for logged-in users, too. When you use them, and have more "levels" of caching than default one, things may really get "fun". Been there, done that, got a massive server down issue ;)

Comment: You are right that pages will be cached and the headers won't be sent again. 
If you did a `header(); die()`, Drupal won't have a chance to cache the page, right? That's a horrible thing to do yes but it is still possible?

Comment: @AyeshK yes, yes it is. But again, it will be a cache breaker. [`drupal_goto`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) is doing basically the same thing, just more gracefully, and it takes care for messages etc. Also, some contrib cache solutions may still cache if you do that this way. Not turning PHP on at all was safest I tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you work drupal try to use drupal API,
Drupal has simple api to redirect [Drupal_goto](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7)

For redirecting to another url just need `drupal_goto('url');`

Comment: And it still may fail in tpl files, you know.